# How to calculate optimal gas limit and gas price?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

Im training to write on Solidity and when I try download ERC20 example in blockchain I need choose gas limit and gas price. How to calculate optimal?
https://www.ethgasstation.info says that with 5 gwei gas price confirmation time will be 0.46 mins, is it true? I read forums and I think this is too few

How much gas limit I need for ERC20 transfer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if it belongs anywhere, it's on a specialized SO for Etherium

Comment: The web3js library has `web3.eth.estimateGas` and `web3.eth.getGasPrice` methods that can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate like this

```
const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
const gasPriceLimit = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
     "from"      : walletbase,       
     "nonce"     : value, 
     "to"        : contractAddr,     
     "data"      : data
})
```